# Simulating Hardware failure of eth ports / cards - is it possible?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, hardware, ethernet

I'm looking for a way to simulate Hardware failure of Ethernet ports/cards.

For example, simulate low speed, or dissconection, without really causing errors.

My goal is that ifconfig or ethtool will catch those "Errors".

Do you think it's possible?

Comment: We're trying to write an automated test , so pulling out the cables is not a good idea for that (:

Comment: You can use [`tc`](http://lartc.org/manpages/tc.txt) on Linux to throttle bandwidth and/or cause packet loss.